# how can i used swift api response call back block

Tags: swift

I would like to return the value after sequentially processing the following code.
It's very different from Android, so I couldn't get the answer I wanted even if I looked at many articles.

finally. I want the value value applied after alamofire was called.

Here's my simplified code.

getParams code

```swift
func getParams() -> [String: Any] {
  val params:[String:Any] = [:]

  for i in 0 ... 5 {
    self.getAPI { completion in

      params[i] = completion
 
      print("test1")
    }
  }

  print("test2")
  return params
}
```

getAPI code

```swift
func getAPI(completion: @escaping([String: String]) -> Void) {

  api(command:"Test", method: "get") { (statusCode, result) in
    if statusCode == 200 {
      if let data = result["data"] as? [String: String] {
        completion(data) // <<-- data is like {"age": "14", "sex":"M", "name":"jenny"}
      }
    }else{
      completion([:])
    }
  }
}
```

My params have nothing.
The order of prints is as follows.
test2 -> test1 -> test1 -> ...

Comment: Watch “Meet async/await” you are mixing asynchronous and synchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

Your completion handler isn't guaranteed to run before your function `getParams` finishes. In fact, given that it looks like you are making an HTTP request, you can pretty much guarantee that the completion handler is not called before `getParams` finishes. `params` will then definitely be empty when you return it.

You need to kick off all of the remaining functionality from your completion handler. Also, the failure route needs to do something instead of just throwing away the response.

In fact, you'll probably want to chain each subsequent call of the completion handler from the previous one, or they won't come back in the right order necessarily.

Comment: Yes, I found out about it this time. But unfortunately, I am not an ios developer.
Can you modify my code?